# After 12.04-14.04 upgrade, Google-talk malfunctions

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, microphone

I have an HP Business 64 bit desktop partitioned between Windows 7(Hp version) and Ubuntu. I upgraded from 12.04 long term to 14.04 long term. Google phone (aka Gmail Call Phone) functioned perfectly in 12.04, using a USB headset w/ microphone. Now there is no incoming sound, (either ring-tones or sound) from the receiver of the phone number being called. I used my own land line to confirm this. At the phone number being called, sound from the USB  mic DOES come through, loud and clear. When the called phone hangs up, it does not end the call in the Google Phone display. Most bizarre of all, this happens with or WITHOUT the Google voice plug-in enabled! It also occurs using both Firefox and Chromium browsers. The plug-in remained in place during the upgrade for both browsers.

During the upgrade, a small window informed that there had been one malfunction.

Has anyone heard of anything else like this? Does this seem like it ought to be a Bug Report?

Can I revert to 12.04? Google phone is a big reason to stay w/ Ubuntu, though it had no effect on my decision to put Ubuntu in my machine.

I'm going to send a report to Gmail about this, but since this a a tiny problem in one operating system, I don't expect much.

FWIW: a big reason for the upgrade was to see if Youtube and other audio and video functions would improve. The improvement is dramatic. Unfortunately, the failure of Google Phone is more dramatic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest confirming that your headset works with something like Audacity, and then try reinstalling the [Google Hangouts plugin from here](https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin). You may also want to remove the Google Hangouts repository using the Software Sources app before attempting to reinstall the plugin. I use this on Ubuntu 14.04 and I was using it on 12.04. I did not do a direct upgrade, but rather backed up my data and did a fresh install of 14.04.